# ggplot facet_grid two variables chromosome mixed up

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a large table that looks like this:

```
Exp Chr Start End Score
BS-seq  Chr1    0   1000    1.24948
BS-seq  Chr1    1000    2000    1.05192
BS-seq  Chr1    2000    3000    0.994919
BS-seq  Chr1    3000    4000    0.915198
...
...
RNA-seq Chr5    26966000    26967000  0.929368
RNA-seq Chr5    26967000    26968000  0.503728
RNA-seq Chr5    26968000    26969000  0.586631
RNA-seq Chr5    26969000    26970000  0.762736
RNA-seq Chr5    26970000    26971000  1.45131
```

I am trying to plot using ggplot and facet_grid, and the data look mixed up when swapping the facet_grid parameter.chromosomes

When using this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Chr, Score), colour=(Exp))) + 
  geom_point(size=.1, alpha = 0.2) +
  labs(x="position (Mb)", y="coverage (mut / WT)") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  facet_grid(Exp ~ Chr)
```

When using `facet_grid(Exp ~ Chr)`, I get this plot:

[image: facet_grid(Exp ~ Chr)]

and when swapping the variables in facet_grid, using `facet_grid(Chr ~ Exp)` everything looks mixed up, like this :

[image: facet_grid(Chr ~ Exp)]

Of course, the plots I wants should look like the second ones (Chr as rows), but I do not want that everything is mixed-up like this.

Comment: Your `color=` should be inside the `aes()`, like `aes(Chr, Score, colour=Exp)`. You must have a different variable named `Exp` outside your data frame where the colors are being pulled from which doesn't get split the same way when faceting.

Comment: have you tried `coord_flip`?

Comment: Additionally, I think it should be `aes(Start, Score, colour = Exp)` or `aes(End, Score, colour = Exp)`, but this may just be a typo on your side as the plots seem to show the position on the x axis (and not the chromosomes as would be the case based on your sample code).

Comment: Sorry, yes “Chr” inside the aes was a typo. I have upgraded my ggplot2 package and everything looks like as expected know. Many thanks.